# How to share database connection between workers using FastAPI + uvicorn?

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to create an app using FastAPI + uvicorn.

This app must be able to handle simultaneous connections. I cannot guarantee that all the code can be executed in a async/await way.

Then, I thought to use the `--workers X` options from uvicorn to handle simultaneous connections, but I need to share the same database connection among all the workers.

I tried the following example:

```
import time
from pymongo.database import Database
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from dynaconf import settings
from pymongo import MongoClient

print("-------> Creating a new MongoDB connection")
db_conn = MongoClient(settings.MONGODB_URI)
db = db_conn.get_database('mydb')

app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    return db

@app.get("/{id}")
async def main(id: str, db: Database = Depends(get_db)):
    print("Recebido id: " + id)
    time.sleep(10)
    return { 'id': id }
```

```
$uvicorn main:app --workers 2
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started parent process [24730]
-------> Creating a new MongoDB connection
-------> Creating a new MongoDB connection
INFO:     Started server process [24733]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Started server process [24732]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

But I'm getting two mongodb connections.

How can I share the MongoDB connection and avoid creating a connection each single worker ?

Comment: Hi @kleyson-rios, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Mabyn No, I didn't.

Answer (score 3):

You must not share the connection, as it's stateful. Two or more processes couldn't be able to use a single socket connection successfully.

Comment: but if my application it's running in the cloud and the number of application grows automatically based on demand, the max number of connection on the MongoDB might get full and block new instances creation. How to deal with this cenario ? There are limits on the mongodb max connection but no limits in the app instances.

Comment: You should only worry about that when it actually happens.

Comment: This is not true, as each connection handles connections pool... this simply means that YOU SHOULD use only one connection per app

Comment: @Yuki OP says "I need to share the same database connection among all the workers and avoid creating a connection each single worker". What I meant with my comment is that you can't share a single socket connection.

Comment: Agreed. Didn’t understand that from context.

Comment: So @Yuki, this idea is to have 1 connection for the pool size per worker? Even if SQLAlchemy is async?